# Opening web browser on boot

Tags: systemd, services

Task: Start Firefox on startup Linux (Ubuntu 18.04 LTS)

Problem: I think the problem is that I want to start a GUI program

What am I doing wrong and how to solve the problem ?

Systemd files in  `~/.config/systemd/user`

Enable: `systemctl --user enable firefox`

My unit file:

````
Description=Start Firefox 
PartOf=graphical-session.target

[Service] 
ExecStart=/usr/bin/firefox
Type=oneshot 

[Install]
WantedBy=graphical-session.target```
````

Comment: Thank you very much ! Actually that was my typo just now :/ it was correct in my system.

Comment: What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: I'll have to provide the screen for firefox to connect to ?

Comment: Yes, of course ! My unit file in ~/.config/systemd/user/firefox.service

Comment: Follow the instructions here https://superuser.com/a/1128905/152474 (just tried on my setup and it works fine)

Comment: It works ! I learned a ton! Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

It works !

Service unit file should go in `~/.config/systemd/user`.

As it is a per-user service, you should manipulate it with the `--user` option to `systemctl`, sans sudo. For example:

Enable: E.g. `systemctl --user enable firefox`

That goes for enabling and disabling it, too.

`~/.config/systemd/user/firefox.service:`

And one part of the systemd people's bodge to make per-user services look like per-login-session services is the whole graphical-session mechanism, which your service unit must incorporate with the setting:

`[Unit] 
PartOf=graphical-session.target`

If `graphical-session.target` is not active after graphical login (you might have an old or stable system).

There was no default hook to run the services at login, so you must trigger it yourself. I do it from my `~/.xsession` file.

`systemctl --user import-environment PATH DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS`
`systemctl --no-block --user start xsession.target`
The first line imports some environment variables into the systemd user session and the second kicks off the target. My `xsession.target` file:

`[Unit]
Description=Xsession running
BindsTo=graphical-session.target`

My unit file:

````
Description=Start Firefox 
PartOf=graphical-session.target

[Service] 
ExecStart=/usr/bin/firefox Type=simple
Restart=on-failure 

[Install] 
WantedBy=xsession.target```
````

Answer (score 0):

1. Any logs `systemctl status firefox.service`(assume firefox.service is the name) may help debug for same problems.
2. Services declared as `oneshot` are expected to take some action and exit immediatelly (thus, they are not really services, no running processes remain). A common pattern for these type of service is to be defined by a setup and a teardown action.

Comment: Thank you, and what should I do ?